# Does Apple accept .app jars on the Mac App Store?

Tags: mac-appstore, automator

I know that I can bundle a `.jar` into a `.app` using Automator and AppleScripts.

However, can this .app be submitted to the App Store?  And if it can be submitted to the App Store, will Apple accept an application of this type?  Are there any examples of apps on the App Store that are `.jar` converted to a `.app`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The question was asking about the Mac App Store, not the iOS App Store. Yes, Apple does accept Java applications into the Mac App Store if packaged correctly. Here are a couple links with more info:

[Packaging for Distribution on a Mac](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/deploy/package_for_mac.html)

[Getting Your Java 8 App in the Mac App Store](http://speling.shemnon.com/blog/2014/04/10/getting-your-java-app-in-the-mac-app-store/)